# Get compressed image from camera in ROS using image_transport

Tags: c++, ros

I'm using ROS version 1 on a turtlebot and I would like to write a C++ program that captures an image in JPEG format, so I can provide the image to a service that needs it to be in that format.  I'm trying to use image_transport and compressed_image_transport to achieve this.  It looks like the basic structure should be:

```
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <compressed_image_transport/compressed_subscriber.h>

<snip>

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::CompressedImage::ConstPtr & msg) { }

<snip>

image_transport::ImageTransport it(n);
compressed_image_transport::CompressedSubscriber sub = it.subscribe("/camera/image/compressed", 1000, imageCallback);
```

However the above gives me compile errors.  If you could recommend the proper way to set this up, it would be greatly appreciated.  I have already run

```
rosmake compressed_image_transport
```

and it built successfully.  Thank you.

Comment: I also wrote some code and it didn't work. Would you like to explain *how* it doesn't work?

Comment: "However the above gives me compile errors."

Comment: And the compile errors are?

Comment: The subscribe function expects a different signature for the callback.

Comment: Can you post the error message? Also try type "const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &msg" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research, I figured out the problem.  Basically, when you want to capture compressed image data, you need to run:

```
rosmake compressed_image_transport
```

as indicated above, to make compressed images available from your camera.  The camera will now publish compressed image topics, as you can determine by running

```
rostopic list
```

after running rosmake above and launching your camera.  Then, in your C++ code, you will want to use:

```
void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::CompressedImage::ConstPtr & msg) { }

<snip>

ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed", 1000, imageCallback);
// (Or whichever topic you wish to subscribe to)
```

to properly receive the compressed image messages from the camera.

Note:  the documentation indicates that the "CompressedImage msg" contains a data[] member; this is actually some boost object, so to get the size of it use msg->data.size().